# Can different threads of one process use more processors?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system

So I thought I read somewhere that only one process can only get **atmost** one processor resource at any given time.  But I also thought I've read somewhere that every thread can get one processor resource at any given time. This latter statement will contradict the first statement as process can exist out of more threads.

So can threads of a process run parallel with other threads of that process? (with parallel I mean running at the same time by means of multiple processors or cores)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question depends upon how threads are implemented on the system.There are two major ways operating systems view the relationship between threads and processes.

1. A process has an address space and is the basic unit scheduled for execution.
2. A process has an address space and the thread is the basic unit scheduled for execution. A process is then an address space and one or more schedulable threads.

In #1 (used on many operating systems) threads are implemented in libraries. The process is responsible for scheduling its own threads. In that threading model, all threads from the same process run interleaved on the same processor (although they may switch processors—together—in some systems). The process can only schedule its own threads to run on the processor the process is running on.

In #2 (the more modern approach) a process's threads can execute concurrently on multiple processors.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, they can!

This is how parallelism is achieved on multi-core system by a multi-threaded program.
Just imagine, if that is not the case then there is no point of having a multi-threaded program on multi-core processor.

Now you might ask how scheduling is achieved on multi-core?
https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/papers/o2:hotos12.pdf